# A fitness workout plan for a female

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines

I'm looking for a solid fitness plan (types of exercises, sets, repetitions, etc.) for kind of getting in shape. I want to train the whole body, use some weights, but I'm not trying to get bulked up or anything. I'd rather do more reps with lower weights.

I found this: www.bodybuilding.com/content/the-female-training-bible-everything-you-need-to-get-the-sexy-body-you-desire.html

But it seems a bit too generic. Are there any professional workout plans that have been accepted by the majority of the fitness instructors?

Thanks for any kind of help, links or directions I should take.

Answer (score 1):

First, read this wiki: https://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/wiki/index

Women aren't some special snowflake and beginners of all genders respond well to the same stimulus. Fortunately you won't get "bulky" without years and years of dedication and focused mass cultivating because women generally find it more difficult to put on muscle mass (not strength!). Doing 50 repetitions of 1kg dumbbell raises won't do anything for you.

Best plans for a beginner looking to get into weightlifting and train the whole body are:

- [Starting Strength](http://web.archive.org/web/20150329092601/http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ:Introduction) (barbell)
- [Strong Lifts 5x5](http://stronglifts.com/) (barbell)
- [kb/recommended_routine](http://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/wiki/kb/recommended_routine) from [r/bodyweightfitness](https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/) (bodyweight)
- [Dumbbell Stopgap](http://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/comments/zc0uy/a_beginner_dumbbell_program_the_dumbbell_stopgap/) (dumbbell)